# Linq SELECT query not returning first row of DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

This should be a real simple operation but for some reason it's not working as expected. I'm trying to copy all the rows out of a DataTable "mainDatatable" that have their Export Cell = 'True'

Here's my code:

```
DataTable table = model.getData.Tables["mainDataTable"].Clone();
var rows = model.getData.Tables["mainDatatable"].Select("Export = 'True'");

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    table.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Now, When i run this it always gets all rows with Export = "True", all but the very first row that is in the DataTable... Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem, creating the `DataTable` with hardcoded data etc? Are you sure that the Export cell doesn't have a value of "True " (with a space) or something similar?

Comment: Not hugely important, but note that this isn't linq - `Select` is [a standard method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `DataTable` class.

Comment: I can't post images because my repuation isn't high enough... I looked through the entries in the Dataset Visualizer and Export is set to "True" for all the entries... it works for everything past the first entry

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any reason why you are not getting this if your table-data is all correct. Please check this:-

Is your `True` actually a string? If Yes, please check the data again. There might be a ***space *** with the 'true' in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with DataTable but in Linq an query isn't build with Select but with Where.

So I would try something like:

```
var rows = model.getData.Tables["mainDatatable"].AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.Field<string>("Export").Equals("true"));
```

or - if its a boolean

```
var rows = model.getData.Tables["mainDatatable"].AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.Field<bool>("Export"));
```